# MySQL duplicate entries search with selective date criteria

Tags: mysql

Having trouble wrapping my head around having an efficient "duplicate entries" select in a single query.

In the below example, duplicate `StockNo` can exist spanning multiple `Date`. I want to search `StockNo` for duplicate entries, and if at least 1 `StockNo` record is found within the `Date` current YEAR-MONTH, then I also need to select its partner that could exist in any other YEAR-MONTH. Is this possible?

**Example Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `sales`
WHERE `StockNo` IN 
    (SELECT `StockNo` FROM `sales` GROUP BY `StockNo` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    AND `Date` LIKE '2016-11-%'
ORDER BY `StockNo`, `TransactionID`;
```

**Example Data:**

```
ID | StockNo | Date
1 | 1 | 2016-11-01
2 | 1 | 2016-11-10
3 | 2 | 2016-11-05
4 | 2 | 2016-10-29
5 | 3 | 2016-10-25
6 | 3 | 2016-10-15
```

With my example query and data, I have 3 pairs of duplicate entries. It's pretty obvious that I will only return 3 records (ID's 1, 2 & 3) due to `AND Date LIKE '2016-11-%'`, however I need to return ID's 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to ignore ID's 5 & 6 because neither of them fall within the current month.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `I want to ignore ID's 5 & 6 because neither of them fall within the current month` ... but doesn't ID 4 also fall not in the current month?  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: Expected output should be ID's 1, 2, 3 & 4 as these records have "at least one" record where Date LIKE '2016-11-%'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT StockNo
FROM sales
GROUP BY StockNo
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

If you also want to retrieve the full records for those matching stock numbers in the above query, you can just add a join:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM sales s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StockNo
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY StockNo
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) s2
    ON s1.StockNo = s2.StockNo
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for pointing me in the right direction. Your answer still only returned records from the current month and in the end I used the following:

Comment: @Stinkys Sorry, the `HAVING` clause should have been `> 0`, not `> 1` ... I updated my answer and it works now as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Tim for pointing me in the right direction. Your answer was close but it still only returned records from the current month and in the end I used the following query:

```
SELECT s1.* FROM `sales` s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM `sales` GROUP BY `StockNo` HAVING COUNT(`StockNo`) > 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%Y-%m')='2016-11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) s2
    ON s1.StockNo=s2.StockNo
```

This one had been eluding me for some time.

Comment: The `COUNT(StockNo`) term seems logically wrong to me, since it would exclude a single `StockNo` which happens to fall in November.  You should use the answer I gave you.

Comment: If I copy your adjusted code to my test DB it selects every record with Date "2016-11-%". As soon as I add "COUNT(`StockNo`) > 1 AND" to the HAVING clause it selects precisely the records I am expecting to see.

Comment: It's basing the GROUP BY on the StockNo and at least 1 Date of current month. Pretty sure it's making sense in my head now.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You _don't_ want `HAVING COUNT(StockNo) > 1` because, again, it would rule out a `StockNo` record which appears by itself for the desired month.

Comment: Forgive me if I am butchering this up, I am just seeing different results with my test database. You can see my [results here](http://imgur.com/a/OCTmv)

Comment: You can't do `SELECT * FROM sales GROUP BY StockNo`, because the only column which can be selected is the `StockNo`.  Actually, you _can_ do this in some versions of MySQL, but it is not defined and really bad practice.  Please have a look at the Fiddle I created for you.

Comment: Yeah I looked at the Fiddle, copied the code straight to my Workbench and went from there, getting completely different results. Is it likely that I have a server config that is changing the outcome?

mysql-server/now 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
mysql-server-5.7/now 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
mysql-server-core-5.7/now 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening on your end.  If you could update the Fiddle with your data and query, then paste the link as a comment here, I can look at it.